# How to read images in path If I have a tensorflow string tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have this simple function below, which takes in a tensorflow string tensor (`filename`) and retrieves an image.

```
def get_image(filename):
    filename = filename.numpy()
    img = tf.io.read_file(f'images/{filename}')
    return img
```

But I get `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`
I looked [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27519) for a solution but nobody had a good solution for this. A lot of people gave suggestions on how to enable eager execution, but none of it worked. Is it really that hard to retrieve data from a tensor...?

Or is there another way to do what I want in this scenario, without converting to numpy?

Answer (score 2):

***TL;DR** First of all, Maybe the below example helps you then you can read a solution for solving and reading images from the path.*

**Example for generating error** *(We can not access to numpy in this type of function)*

```
# With @tf.function
@tf.function
def func(tns):
    tf.print(tns.numpy())
func(tf.random.uniform(shape=(2,)))
# ->  AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'


# Without @tf.function
def func(tns):
    tf.print(tns.numpy())
func(tf.random.uniform(shape=(2,)))
# -> array([0.86797523, 0.10352373], dtype=float32)
```

**Solution:**
For reading images from your path you need to consider:

1. Create a list of paths with `os.path.join` that you want to read images from it.
2. After reading images make sure to use [`tf.image.decode_png`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_png).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

path = 'images'
path_images = [os.path.join(path, img) for img in os.listdir(path)] 
img_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(path_images)

def get_image(filename):
    img = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    img = tf.image.decode_png(img, channels=3)
    return img


img_dataset = img_dataset.map(get_image, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
for img in img_dataset.take(1):
    print(img.shape)
# (100, 100, 3)
```

Creating random images in path `/images/`:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

for i in range(10):
    imarray = np.random.rand(100,100,3) * 255
    im = Image.fromarray(imarray.astype('uint8')).convert('RGB')
    im.save(f'images/image_{i}.png')
```